# C# Lambda expression to pull all names by comma separated ids

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have roled ids in a comma separated string. I am trying to pull role names from db based on the role id each separately inside loop.

Is there any option to get all rolenames at once using linq or lambda expression?

For example I have

```
var roleIds = "1,3,5,9";
```

Similar to the lambda expression below to pull one role name can I pull all role names for role ids in a single line code with out a loop?

```
for (var i; i < mycommaseperatedRoleIds.count; i++)
    var roleName = db.Roles.Where(k => k.Id == roleId).Select(p => p.Role);
```

Comment: You've written pseudo-code - you talk about `roleIds` being a string, but then you're using `mycommaseperatedRoleIds` - is that already meant to be a list? Please provide real, valid code rather than pseudo-code, otherwise it'll be a lot harder to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var roleIds ="1,3,5,9".Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s));

var roleNames = db.Roles.Where(k => roleIds.Contains(k.Id)).Select(p => p.Role);
```

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray()`